# Azure Elastic Pool - is it supported for MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, azure-sql-database, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I know that Elastic Pool in Azure is supported for SQL Server.
But I could not find any information if it is supported for MySQL.
I could not find any information in documentation at all what types of databases are supported...
Can you please assist me since I need to provide this info ASAP?

THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, yes.  An Azure Database for MySql is similar to an Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool or Azure SQL Database Managed Instance.

> Within an Azure Database for MySQL server, you can create one or
> multiple databases. **You can opt to create a single database per server
> to use all the resources or to create multiple databases to share the
> resources**. The pricing is structured per-server, based on the
> configuration of pricing tier, vCores, and storage (GB). For more
> information, see Pricing tiers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-servers

An Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool is similarly:

> Azure SQL Database elastic pools are a simple, cost-effective solution
> for managing and scaling multiple databases that have varying and
> unpredictable usage demands. **The databases in an elastic pool are on a
> single server and share a set number of resources at a set price.**
> Elastic pools in Azure SQL Database enable SaaS developers to optimize
> the price performance for a group of databases within a prescribed
> budget while delivering performance elasticity for each database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview

Only Azure SQL Database has the feature to have lots of databases with separate physical resources in the same logical server.  With Azure Database for MySql if you want two databases to have their own dedicate resources, you need two seperate Azure Databases for MySQL servers.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for response. I will mark it as response.
But I would like to use multiple databases on single server - like that is the case for Elastic Pool - so I think this sentence from the official doc is not so relevant ..."create a single database per server to use all the resources "... am I right?

Comment: It's the ability to "create multiple databases to share the resources" that is like an elastic pool.

Comment: Thanks. I marked the answer :) Also, could you be so kind to send me a link where I can compare the prices for SQL Server Elastic Pool costs and costs for its equivalent  for Azure Database for MySql? For example to have 10 databases in Elastic Pool and 10 databases in Azure Database for MySQL with exact same configuration (CPUs, RAM...)
Thanks